Проблема с бесконечными обновлениями у pwa приложения в safari
Столкнулся с проблемой бесконечного обновления страницы в сафари. Также, по не известной мне причине, подгружается старый кэш, который должен быть удален уже давно. Приложение использует библиотеку vite-pwa.
vite.config.ts


import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";
// https://vitejs.dev/config/export

const isProd = true;

const defaultData = {
  strategies: "injectManifest",
  start_url: "/index.html",
  injectManifest: {
    rollupFormat: "iife",
  },
  registerType: "autoUpdate",
  srcDir: "src",
  filename: "sw.ts",
  devOptions: {
    enabled: true,
    type: "module",
  },
  workbox: {
    skipWaiting: true,
    clientsClaim: true,
    cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
  },
  manifest: {
    name: "",
    short_name: "",
    description: "",
    start_url: "/",
    display: "standalone",
    background_color: "#272238",
    orientation: "portrait",
    related_applications: [
      {
        platform: "webapp",
        url: "https://sandbox.desire.fans/manifest.json",
      },
    ],
    url_handlers: [
      {
        origin: "https://sandbox.desire.fans",
      },
    ],
    icons: [
      {
        src: "/manifest/manifest192.png",
        sizes: "192x192",
        type: "image/png",
      },
      {
        src: "/manifest/manifest512.png",
        sizes: "512x512",
        type: "image/png",
        purpose: "apple touch icon",
      },
      {
        src: "/manifest/favicon.svg",
        sizes: "512x512",
        type: "image/png",
        purpose: "image/svg",
      },
      {
        src: "/manifest/manifest500.png",
        sizes: "144x144",
        type: "image/png",
        purpose: "maskable",
      },
      {
        src: "/manifest/manifest96.png",
        sizes: "96x96",
        type: "image/png",
      },
      {
        src: "/manifest/manifest144.png",
        sizes: "144x144",
        type: "image/png",
      },
      {
        src: "/manifest/manifest512.png",
        sizes: "512x512",
        type: "image/png",
      },
    ],
  },
};

const pwaConfig = isProd ? defaultData : {};

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: undefined,
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [react(), VitePWA(pwaConfig)],
});



sw.ts


// Import Cache Names and ClientClaim module for providing the cache name and taking control of all pages immediately
// @ts-ignore
import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";

// Import routing modules for registering routes and setting default and catch handlers
import {
  registerRoute,
  setCatchHandler,
  setDefaultHandler,
} from "workbox-routing";

// Import caching modules for caching strategies
import { NetworkFirst, NetworkOnly, Strategy } from "workbox-strategies";

// Import module for caching precached assets
import type { ManifestEntry } from "workbox-build";

// Give TypeScript the correct global.
declare let self: any;

// Declare type for ExtendableEvent to use in install and activate events
declare type ExtendableEvent = any;

// Access the pre-defined cache names for use in this app
const cacheName = "CACHE_APP-1.0.9";

// Configure the strategy for handling all requests based on the data object
const buildStrategy = (): Strategy => {
  return new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName,
    plugins: [
      {
        cacheWillUpdate: async ({ request, response }) => {
          console.log(request);
          if (
            !response ||
            response.status !== 200 ||
            response.type !== "basic"
          ) {
            return null;
          }
          return response;
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};

// Retrieve the manifest. First define asynchronous function to retrieve the manifest
const manifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST as Array<ManifestEntry>;

// Array for resources that have been cached by the service worker
const cacheEntries: RequestInfo[] = [];

// Run through the manifest and cache all resources
const manifestURLs = manifest.map((entry) => {
  const url = new URL(entry.url, self.location.href);
  cacheEntries.push(new Request(url.href, { credentials: "same-origin" }));
  return url.href;
});

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  const cacheWhitelist = [cacheName];
  self.skipWaiting();
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (!cacheWhitelist.includes(cacheName)) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
});

// Upon activating the service worker, clear outdated caches by removing caches associated with
// URL resources that are not in the manifest URL array
self.addEventListener("activate", (event: ExtendableEvent) => {
  const currentCacheName = cacheName;
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cache) => {
          if (cache !== currentCacheName) {
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

// Register all URLs that are found in the manifest and use the buildStrategy function to cache them
registerRoute(({ url }) => manifestURLs.includes(url.href), buildStrategy());

// Inform the service worker to send all routes that are not recognized to the network to be fetched
setDefaultHandler(new NetworkOnly());

// This method is called when the service worker is unable to fetch a resource from the network
setCatchHandler(({ event }: any): Promise<Response> => {
  switch (event.request.destination) {
    case "document":
      return caches.match("/index.html").then((response) => {
        return response || Promise.reject("no-match");
      });
    default:
      return Promise.reject("no-match");
  }
});



